# Setting HTML source for QtWebKit to a string value vs. file.read(), encoding issue?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtwebkit, pyqt5

I have a script that reads a bunch of JavaScript files into a variable, and then places the contents of those files into placeholders in a Python template. This results in the value of the variable `src` (described below) being a valid HTML document including scripts.

```
# Open the source HTML file to get the paths to the JavaScript files
f = open(srcfile.html, 'rU')
src = f.read()
f.close()

js_scripts = re.findall('script\ssrc="(.*)"', src)

# Put all of the scripts in a variable
js = ''
for script in js_scripts:
    f = open(script, 'rU')
    js = js + f.read() + '\n'
    f.close()

# Open/read the template
template = open('template.html)
templateSrc = Template(template.read())

# Substitute the scripts for the placeholder variable
src = str(templateSrc.safe_substitute(javascript_content=js))

# Write a Python file containing the string
with open('htmlSource.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n\nhtmlSrc = """' + src + '"""')
```

If I try to open it up via PyQt5/QtWebKit in Python...

```
from htmlSource import htmlSrc
webWidget.setHtml(htmlSrc)
```

...it doesn't load the JS files in the web widget. I just end up with a blank page.

But if I get rid of everything else, and just write to file `'"""src"""'`, when I open the file up in Chrome, it loads everything as expected. Likewise, it'll also load correctly in the web widget if I read from the file itself:

```
f = open('htmlSource.py', 'r')
htmlSrc = f.read()
webWidget.setHtml(htmlSrc)
```

In other words, when I run this script, it produces the Python output file with the variable; then I try to import that variable and pass it to `webWidget.setHtml()`; but the page doesn't render. But if I use `open()` and read it as a file, it does.

I suspect there's an encoding issue going on here. But I've tried several variations of `encode` and `decode` without any luck. The scripts are all UTF-8.

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7, can't use Python 3 because I'm using a library elsewhere in the code that only works with Python2 currently.